# What are the advantages of the knowledge that a corpus of text follows the zipf's law?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have the frequency count of all the words from a file (that i am using to analyze and index data: elasticsearch), and the frequency of words follows zipf's law. How can i use this knowledge to improve my search over it? Rather, how can i use it to get anything done to my benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very interesting question, and I'm sad that it's gone without answer or comment for so long. Zipfian distribution is a phenomenon that occurs not only in language, but far beyond that.

### Zipf and Pareto

Zipfian distribution or Zipf's Law is a rank-frequency distribution of words in this case. But perhaps more importantly pareto distribution implies that approximately 20% of words(cause) account for roughly 80% of word occurrences(outcome) in any given body, or bodies, of text. Lucene, the brain behind elasticsearch, accounts for this in multiple ways, and often beyond that of zipf's law. It's common that your results will contain a zipfian distribution.

### Word frequency, least is best(usually)

One of the problems here is in most bodies of text the most common words actually bare the least context. Usually being an article or having a very limited context. The top 3 most common words in english are: "the", "of", and "to". Elasticsearch actually comes with a list of [stop words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html) which will optimize indexing by ignoring articles.

Elasticsearch stop words:

> a, an, and, are, as, at, be, but, by, for, if, in, into, is, it, no,
> not, of, on, or, such, that, the, their, then, there, these, they,
> this, to, was, will, with

It's actually a common occurrence that words that appear the least frequent bare the most context. So you're likely going to look for the least frequent words when doing text search.

### 80:20 phenomenon

The thing is elasticsearch and lucene are both build with these things in mind, and well optimised for such. A simple [LRU eviction policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Examples) for caching indices actually works very well, as 80% of your searches will likely use 20% of your actual indices making cache pollution both infrequent and low impact due to a predictable workload. So if you allocate a cache size larger than 20% your total index size you should be fine. In the event that the index is not in cache it will read off the disk(usually mmap), and you can optimize performance by having a drive with fast random reads(like an SSD).

### More Reading

There is an interesting [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/stop-redesigning-start-tuning-your-site/) on this. Its likely that the total word rank in your data set looks very similar to that of the word rank of most other data sets. So optimizing performance as well as relevance is left to those few words which are likely to occur least often, but are likely to be most search for. This may be jargon in context to the demographic/profession your application is targeting.

### Conclusion

These optimizations, however, could be premature. Like I stated, lucene and elasticsearch both do their part to increase effectiveness and efficiency of search with these principles in mind. Like I stated earlier, a simple LRU cache works very well in this case, and LRU is both common(already part of ES) and relatively simple. Cases where it might be worth-while are usually cases where you have a lot of jargon or specific language or perhaps multilingual. For something like a news site you'll likely want a more broad solution, as you cover a huge spectrum of topics which include many different words and subjects. These are usually things to consider when you're configuring elasticsearch, but tinkering with the analyzer can be complicated and may be hard to do effectively especially if you have a large range of subjects with different terminologies that you need to index, however this will likely have the largest effect on increasing search relevance.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question!!